# Pass parameter via angular with php, in SQL to Where

Tags: php, angular, oracle

If you pass the fixed id, without being per variable it works.If you leave the variable, the result is blank. The code works perfectly, it may be that the variable inside `PHP` does not load, I do not know if it would have a better way to run.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
   <td>{{user.NNUMERO}}</td>
   <td>
      {{user.OBJETO}} 
      <br>
      <div class="panel-group">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{user.NNUMERO}}">Arquivos</a>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="{{user.NNUMERO}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul>
                     <?php
                        //ID
                        $CDLICITACAO = "{{ user.CDLICITACAO }}";

                        $conn = oci_connect('SYSTEM', '123', '127.0.0.1/xe');
                        if (!$conn) {
                            $e = oci_error();
                            trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
                        }

                        $query = 'SELECT * FROM SDNVW_ARQLICITACAO_TRANSP WHERE CDLICITACAO = :id';
                        $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
                        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":id", $CDLICITACAO);
                        oci_execute($stid);
                        while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
                            echo $row['IDANEXO'] ."<br>\n";
                        }

                        oci_free_statement($stid);
                        oci_close($conn);

                        ?>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td> {{user.DTABERTURA | date:'d m, yyyy'  }}</td>
   <td>{{user.DESCSTATUS}}</td>
   <td>{{user.DTSTATUS}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Wth is `$idt` ?

Comment: had changed, the correct is $CDLICITACAO

Comment: Are you trying to make angular put something into php variable?

Comment: Yes, I need to get the ID = CDLICITACAO, for the sql ...

Comment: The client server interaction doesn't work that way. When the page is received by the browser the PHP part is already executed.

Comment: I understand, would you have any other way to run this code?

Comment: I usually use ajax call to load such data in json format and make the spa framework handle the rest.

Comment: Do you have any examples that I can follow?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find one. Basically my idea was to make the ajax on init and assign it to the user object,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question.
You post to the page where you will process the values in the post variable. But you need to pick it up from input...

```
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($postdata);
```

I find the easiest way to deal with the incoming values is to in Angular make the Table and the Operation values in the Post Object being past..

```
login(login: Login): Observable<Login> {

  const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type':  'application/json'})};

  const newObj = {...login, T: 'login', R: 'login'};

  const finalstring = JSON.stringify(newObj);

  return this.http.post<User>(this.loginUrl, finalstring, httpOptions)

 .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

but am always up for learning something if somebody has a better way